# Run SSIS package using T-SQL under different account

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I normally run an SSIS package using a Sql Agent Job and a proxy user as described here: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/run-an-ssis-package-under-a-different-account

I now need to run the same package using the same proxy user using T-SQL. I've been trying to use the `[catalog].[create_execution]` and `[catalog].[start_execution]` procedures to do this but there doesn't seem to be a way to specify a user.

How do I execute a package as a different user?

Is my best recourse the use of T-SQL to execute a SQL Agent Job that is configured to use the proxy user instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how agent actually works to make proxy users work - especially with regard to SSIS packages.

In a "normal" sql session say in SSMS, if I wanted to run a query as another user

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'TurgidWizard';
SELECT USER_NAME() AS WhoAmI;
REVERT;
```

That code would allow me to impersonate you until I hit the `REVERT` call.

But, if you swap out calls to create_execution/start_execution you'll run into the same issue as trying to use a local sql server user runs into with using the methods in the SSISDB - it doesn't work. The methods in the SSISDB all run checks before they begin to ensure users have the correct access level and there isn't impersonation going on. Because once those methods start running, they themselves do impersonation so I guess that doesn't work well.

How can I run a package using tsql under a different account? I would start SSMS/sqlcmd under the credentials using [RUNAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11)) For example, the following will open a new command window as you.

```
runas /netonly /user:corpdomain.com\turgiwizard "cmd"
```

From there, things I do will be under the aegis of your user so I could run sqlcmd calls like

```
sqlcmd -S TheServer -d SSISDB -Q "EXECUTE catalog.create_execution ...;"
```

Mouse click will be Ctrl+Shift+right click executable.

[image: Run as different user]

Your SSMS install location is version dependent but try various ten digit increments of 140 in the following path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
```

The downside for me with regard to runas is that I could not automate getting my credentials passed into it. I've seen articles about use auto hot key and such but never had any luck with it.

Cleanest/easiest approach for something that needs to run regularly is to use sql agent with a proxy, or you could use Windows Task Scheduler and create it as the target user. One off executions, I'd likely use the runas approach.